# How to select only one pragraph in html and to change color with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have only one paragraph to select please tell me how select with jQuery the first paragraph

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help you http://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted to write yourself to solve this problem.

Comment: What's wrong with google???

Comment: These type of questions leads to [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can select them in different ways

Here you can select the elements by number...

```
$("div").children(':nth-child(1)').css("background", "red"); 
// $("div").children(':nth-child(1)').html(); // for content
```

or

```
$("div p:nth-child(1)").css("background", "red");
```

than you could use the first-child selector

```
$("div").children(':first-child').css("background", "red");
```

or

```
$("div p:first-child").css("background", "red");
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wh5S9/1/)**

more solutions by kaypaul (posted in comments)

```
$("div p").eq(1).css('background-color','#ccc');
$("div p").eq(3).addClass('bg-blue');
```

**[kaypauls JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/5xSxK/8/)**

Comment: $("div p").eq(based-0-num).css('background-color','#your-color'); To change background color you can add a class instead css(), like this $("div p").eq(based-0-num).addClass('bg-blue'); here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/keypaul/5xSxK/8/

Comment: @Praveen that's not right... check the fiddle ;)

Comment: @keypaul added to post :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").children(':first-child').css('color', 'red')
```

**or**

```
$("div").children(':nth-child(1)').css('color', 'green')
```

**or**

```
$("div p:first-child").css('color', 'blue')
```